# How to diff two table using spark sql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, apache-spark-sql

Now I need to diff two table using spark sql,i find a sql server's answer like this :

```
(SELECT *
 FROM   table1
 EXCEPT
 SELECT *
 FROM   table2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
 FROM   table2
 EXCEPT
 SELECT *
 FROM   table1)
```

Hope somebody can tell me how to using spark sql like this in sql server? (Do not care the special col ,just use *)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this something like this :

```
scala> val df1=sc.parallelize(Seq((1,2),(3,4))).toDF("a","b")
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int]

scala> val df2=sc.parallelize(Seq((1,2),(5,6))).toDF("a","b")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int]

scala> df1.create
createOrReplaceTempView   createTempView

scala> df1.createTempView("table1")

scala> df2.createTempView("table2")

scala> spark.sql("select * from table1 EXCEPT select * from table2").show
+---+---+                                                                       
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  3|  4|
+---+---+


scala> spark.sql("(select * from table2 EXCEPT select * from table1) UNION ALL (select * from table1 EXCEPT select * from table2)").show
+---+---+                                                                       
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  5|  6|
|  3|  4|
+---+---+
```

**Note :** In your case you have to make dataframe out of the JDBC calls and then register the table and perform the operations.

Comment: Wouldn't a Join on a specific primary Key be more efficient? Using Except will compare every row in tableA to every row in tableB correct?